# Compare file sturcture on drive to file structure in XML using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, compare

**Below are the details of my question**

I have a .sqlproj file which contains **XML** of the builds, files and locations, the file looks something like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="WriteDacVersion;Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
   <ItemGroup>
     <Folder Include="dbo\" />
      <Folder Include="dbo\Tables\" />
      <Folder Include="dbo\Stored Procedures" />
    <Folder Include="dbo\Function" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
     <Build Include="stock\Tables\stock.tblTable.sql" />
     <Build Include="stock\Stored Procedures\stock.spStoredProc.sql" />
     <Build Include="stock\Functions\stock.Function.sql" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**I would like to know 2 things,**

**1.** How to check the physical drive locations and files to the locations and files in the XML

**2.** Iterate through and if the file and path matches the physical to the XML, thats fine, but if it doesn't match, i.e, file on drive and not in xml, throw and error.

Comment: Have you tried loading and parsing the XML? If yes, could you show what you've tried?

Comment: This looks at the XML and tries to find the files on the drive. What i want is to find the files on the drive inside the XML.

string[] notFoundSps = xdoc.Descendants("ItemGroup")
                    .Descendants("Build")
                    .Select(s => s.Attribute("Include"))
                    .Select(s => s.Value)
                    .Where(s => s.Contains("Stored Procedures"))
                    .Where(sp => !File.Exists(sp))
                    .OrderBy(sp => sp)
                    .ToArray();

Answer (score 0):

I still cant figure out how to do it in Linq, so i resorted to do it the normal way, this is my code...

```
            // grab the files and locations out of the xml file.
            string[] xmlFiles = xdoc.Descendants("ItemGroup")
                .Descendants("Build")
                .Select(s => s.Attribute("Include"))
                .Select(s => s.Value)
                .Where(s => s.Contains("Stored Procedures") || s.Contains("Tables") || s.Contains("Functions") || s.Contains("Views"))
                .ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < xmlFiles.Length; i++)
            {
                string fileXml = xmlFiles[i];

                // get just the file name
                string path = fileXml;
                string[] pathArr = path.Split('\\');
                string[] fileArr = pathArr.Last().Split('\\');
                string fileNameXml = fileArr.Last().ToString();

                String[] filesOnDrive = Directory.GetFiles(_filePath, fileNameXml, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                for (int j = 0; j == filesOnDrive.Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("no file = " + fileNameXml);
                }
            }
```

In Linq, I think, i need to do a left Join on this,

```
           //Get folder list from xml
            string[] folders = xdoc.Descendants("ItemGroup")
                .Descendants("Folder")
                .Select(f => f.Attribute("Include"))
                .Select(f => f.Value)
                .Where(f => f.Contains(("Stored Procedures")))
                //.Where(f => File.Exists(fileName))
                .ToArray();
```

And this,

```
           // grab the files and locations out of the xml file.
           string[] sps = xdoc.Descendants("ItemGroup")
               .Descendants("Build")
               .Select(s => s.Attribute("Include"))
               .Select(s => s.Value)
               .Where(s => s.Contains("Stored Procedures"))
               .ToArray();
```

If anyone has any ideas, I would really appreciate it.